# Can't get MongoDB started on 18.04

Tags: mongodb

Apologies if this has been asked a bunch of times (it has, sorry!) but I can't find a solution that works.

I'm line for line following:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-ubuntu/

When I `sudo systemctl start mongdb`:

```
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Sat 2021-10-02 17:28:51 EEST; 15min ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 10714 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
 Main PID: 10714 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
```

I've updated the `mongod.service` file as per [this answer][1]

and in accordance with the answers in that same question, ran the following commands:

```
chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb
chown mongodb:mongodb /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
```

though for also ran it for `var/log/mongodb` (note that these folders are empty? I created a txt file named `mongodb.log` manually, the file itself is empty and there are no mongo related files in `tmp`, so the latter command of course failed

Given some of these folders are missing/empty, I ran

```
mk@Swankey:~$ sudo mongod --repair
Illegal instruction
```

So following [this question][2] I tried the following commands, nothing has changed, still at square one here.

```
:~$ sudo rm -r /var/lib/mongodb
:~$ sudo mkdir -p /var/lib/mongodb/
:~$ sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb/
:~$ sudo mkdir -p /var/log/mongodb/
:~$ sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/log/mongodb/
:~$ sudo systemctl restart mongod
:~$ sudo systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
   Active: failed (Result: core-dump) since Sat 2021-10-02 17:18:09 EEST; 7s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 10657 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf (code=dumpe
 Main PID: 10657 (code=dumped, signal=ILL)
```

PS I have ran `purge mongo*` and reinstalled multiple times I'm at a loss here

Similar to the second question thread linked, when I install the package `mongodb` (as opposed to `mongodb-org` the service will run? I'd prefer to follow the official documentation hence using `mongodb-org`

```
  [1]: https://askubuntu.com/a/884652
  [2]: https://askubuntu.com/questions/929198/fail-to-start-mongod-service-but-mongodb-service
  [3]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29554521/uninstall-mongodb-from-ubuntu
```

Comment: @user535733 I've edited now, the first one at least, only 'enabled' was cut off so I didn't edit the second message (which is the same anyway)

Answer (score 1):

Ok so after several failures and online searching, I've come across [this answer in StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68392064/error-when-running-mongo-image-docker-entrypoint-sh-line-381/68394912#68394912), which basically suggests MongoDB 5.0 needs a newer cpu in order to run

I'll admit that I've not actually tried this yet (downgrading) due to the constraints (already wasted a full weekend on this) but it is highly possible to be the case given my cpu is quite old, and that when I downloaded the `mongodb` package (as in the Ubuntu one, not the 'offical' `mongodb-org` package, it worked. I believe this Ubuntu `mongodb` package is the 3.somthing version)

I'll leave this as a potential answer as I'm sure it may help someone with a laptop as old as mine.

Will edit if this works for me